# How to truncate each list in a list of lists?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists, and in each list I want to truncate all values after the first two.

Here is an example with my attempt

```
listss = [ [ 2, 4, 5, 7 ,7], [4, 5,], [2,4 ,4 ,4,4,7,9]]

for item in listss:
    item = item[0:2]
```

However, this does not alter any of the lists.

The desired result should look like

```
[ [ 2, 4], [4, 5], [2,4]]
```

Comment: `new_listss = [x[:2] for x in listss]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete slices in the sub-lists in-place:

```
for item in listss:
    del item[2:]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
listss = [[2, 4, 5, 7, 7], [4, 5, ], [2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 9]]

for i, item in enumerate(listss):
    listss[i] = item[:2]

print(listss)
```